# UNION ALL vs UNPIVOT to change column values into rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

Why would one want to use one method over the other for taking several column values and moving them into rows with a label classifier and a value column?

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UNPIVOT` is better from a performance perspective because it only scans the rows once.  `UNION ALL` is going to scan the rows once for every subquery.  In theory, this doesn't have to happen, but I don't know of an optimizer that would only do one scan.

This is particularly important for large tables or if the "table" is really a complex SQL expression or view.